# How does SourceDNA track SDKs used by apps

Tags: ios, sdk, reverse-engineering

I just got done reading the press hysteria around AFNetworking exposing apps to a man in the middle attack.  I was surprised that sourcedna.com claims

> SourceDNA analyzes the code in thousands of iOS & Android apps.

sourcedna.com even has a search engine to report whether a vendor's apps use the AFNetworking SDK.

Considering they don't have access to paid apps, how do they claim to do this?  Do SDKs like AFNetworking log SDK use in some form?  If so, to who?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I replied to @janselrx, I believe it's as I suspected and they can only analyze free apps. From their website:

> SourceDNA analyzes the code in thousands of iOS & Android apps. This report lets you explore recent data about the mobile SDKs and tools found in the top 500 free apps.

Comment: Hey @Dan, after my first comment, I contacted the SourceDNA team to get more information on this, they told me that libraries are recognized by their analytic tools when a handful of apps start using it, but at the same time developers can submit a request to be added manually and be recognized after that.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious about this too. Here is what I gather:

SourceDNA only checks whether the library is linked into the app binary. They do not check how or whether the library is actually used by the app.

Objective-C is a dynamic language and keeps a lot of metadata in the binary. You can trivially run tools like `class-dump` or `otool -ov` on any unencrypted binary and it will list the names and inheritance of all classes, and the names and signatures of all methods and instance variables in each class, among other things.

Libraries like AFNetworking have many distinctive class names that they can check for in the list of classes in the app. Each version will have some added or removed methods and/or instance variables, so by checking the class dump from the app against the class declarations from each version of the library, they can figure out the version of the library used.

However, apps downloaded from the App Store are encrypted; and the App Store is the only way that SourceDNA could have gotten these apps. It is possible to decrypt / crack encrypted apps (that is how people pirate paid apps -- they buy them, crack them, and post the unencrypted binaries on pirate websites), but the common way to do this I believe involves buying and running the app on a jailbroken device.

I assume that the SourceDNA people must have automated this process somehow, so that they can automatically report on thousands of apps.

Comment: I've done the forensics on my apps and free apps.  Obviously, I can't analyze an app until it's been downloaded and it can't be downloaded without purchasing a paid app.  I'm most concerned that libraries are "calling home" or using some kind of tracking mechanism in order for this information to be captured.

Comment: @Dan: Well, AFNetworking is open-source so you can check for yourself

Comment: thanks for the interest and replies.  My original post was prompted by the vendor claims.  I'll update if I discover anything new.

Comment: Hey @Dan , have you discovered something about this ?

Comment: @janselrx, sorry for the tardy response.  I believe it's as I suspected, they can only analyze free apps.  From their website: "SourceDNA analyzes the code in thousands of iOS & Android apps. This report lets you explore recent data about the mobile SDKs and tools found in the top 500 free apps."